# Issue when enabling the interpreter only for the System.Linq.Expression assembly for MAUI project

Tags: ios, .net, xamarin.ios, maui, .net-7.0

I need to set the interpreter only for the System.Linq.Expression assembly for MAUI project only for iOS when I am setting using below line I am getting build issues.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <MtouchInterpreter>-all,System.Linq.Expressions</MtouchInterpreter>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Below is the issue which I am facing.

```
Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(1007, 3): Failed to AOT compile Microsoft.iOS.dll, the AOT compiler exited with code 134
```

Can some one help me out with this issue ?

Comment: You could refer to this issue: [App crashes ONLY in "release && real-iphone && interpreter" for no apparent reason, even with try-catch around the call](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/16413). From [rolfbjarne comment](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/16413#issuecomment-1294904679), -all cause the error.

Comment: I have not heard from you for a couple of days. Do you still meet this issue?